# MongoDB add fields to an object inside an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I changed my structure from array of Objects to hash map, but I cannot add fields to the Objects inside the Object contains them.

Structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eec94b38c43486fc8fc268b"),
    // more unrelated properties
    "orders" : {
        "275993831" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eec955cb5d72877000b9f40"),
            // more unrelated properties
            "externalOrderId" : "275993831",
        },
        "276031671" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5eecab569f90bc4becf05a8b"),
            // more unrelated properties
            "externalOrderId" : "276031671",
        }
    }
}
```

The `externalOrderId` is the ID I receive from the API I call, what I'd like to do is to add more fields to the objects inside `orders`, I have the `user._id` and `externalOrderId`, all the queries I have been trying did not work.

The latest one:

```
users.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        '_id': ObjectId(userId),
        'orders.externalOrderId': externalOrderId
    },
    {
        $set: { 'msg': response }
    }
)
```

Comment: Which queries did you try?

Comment: @D. SM added an example, it had many different tries, that's the last one..

Comment: Does that query find anything?

Comment: MongoDB has https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/ which would require changing your id-indexed order map into an array.

Comment: @D.SM It worked before when the order property was an array, but in the future some users might have thousands of orders, I didn't want to loop through it (searches, selection etc) on both front and back. I need to pull a specific order from the orders (object/array) on the front side, and hash map is O(1) unlike array O(n). do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Embedding thousands of orders sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @D.SM I have to store the orders in order to show them to the clients, so a client can see his orders history.. that's why I preferred hash map over array when it's about big amount of data.

Comment: Showing orders requires neither embedding nor hash maps.